# Trying to update password (GraphQL) "data must be a string and salt must either be a salt string"

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm new to graphQL and I'm trying to update the user profile password in the backend under my resolvers.js file but I've been stuck at it for a while and I keep getting the same error message.

[image]

**resolvers.js**

```
updatePassword: combineResolvers(
  isAuthenticated,
  async (parent, args, context) => {
    const { id, newPassword, oldPassword } = args;
    const { models, user, jwtSecret } = context;

    await models.User.updatePassword(
      { id, newPassword, oldPassword },
      createToken({ newPassword }, jwtSecret, API_TIMEOUTS.JWT_TOKEN),
      user.emailAddress
    );

    return models.User.findByEmail(user.emailAddress);
  }
)
```

**Index.js (helper)**

```
 const generatePasswordHash = async password => {
      const saltRounds = 10;
      return bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
    }

  User.updatePassword = async (newPassword, emailAddress) => {
    const password = await generatePasswordHash(newPassword);

        return User.update(
            { password, resetPasswordToken: null },
            {
                where: {
                    emailAddress
                }
            }
        );
    };
```

Error that I'm getting

*"data must be a string and salt must either be a salt string or a number of rounds"*

Comment: could you provide `generatePasswordHash` code too? the problem seems to occur in this function

Comment: Yup no worries, just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.updatePassword` takes only 2 arguments, the first being the password. You are invoking it with 3. The problem is you are providing an object for the password (`{ id, newPassword, oldPassword }`) and bcrypt doesn't like that